# jQuery selector on custom attribute value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand some jQuery syntax that I did not originally write.

```
<span id="mySpanElement" toggle-state="ON">Some Sample Text</span>

function switchOff(selectedControl) {
    var fieldName = selectedControl.attr('toggle-state');
    var newState = fieldName.replace("ON", "OFF");
    return $("[toggle-state='" + newState + "']");
}
```

In this function does the return statement pass back a reference to an element in the DOM that has an attribute of `toggle-state=OFF`? I have never seen a selector based upon a custom attribute before and was unsure if I am understanding it correctly.

Comment: It appears as if the function will return an array of all objects with the custom attribute, `toggle-state` matching whatever state it has been toggled to. Interesting concept...

Comment: As a tip, I would add that when in doubt, open up the Chrome developer tools, find the code (on the source tab), put a break point on the JavaScript and when the break point is hit switch to the console tab and paste in the JavaScript.  For example, if I put a break point on the return statement and when it was hit, I could paste $("[toggle-state='" + newState + "']") into the console tab and it would spit out an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `"[toggle-state='" + newState  + "']"` will match every element in the document that has the attribute `toggle-state` set to `newState` ("OFF" in this case).

Using that selector as an argument with jQuery will create a jQuery object that contains the resulting set of matches. That construction is what is being returned.

Here is a simple demonstration

```js
function switchOff(){
 var newState = "OFF";
 return $("[toggle-state='" + newState  + "']")
}

$("#result").text(
    //$("[toggle-state='" + newState  + "']").length
    switchOff().length
);
```

```css
[toggle-state="ON"]{
  color:green;
}
[toggle-state="OFF"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div toggle-state="ON">Some Sample Text</div>
<div toggle-state="OFF">Some Sample Text</div>
<div toggle-state="OFF">Some Sample Text</div>
<div toggle-state="ON">Some Sample Text</div>
<div toggle-state="OFF">Some Sample Text</div>
<div id="result"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns all elements with the attribute `toggle-state` equal to `OFF`.